# (C#) When adding a struct and a number together into a string, the number doesn't show up

Tags: c#, console

so, I started making this struct called stringW, and overloaded and defined a buncs of operators:
However, when I tried writing it in the console, for some reason when I add 3 to the string when b is present, the three at the end doesn't not show up. Did I mess up something? I'm not an expert at classes/structs, but I didn't saw anything like this. Here's the code:

```csharp
public struct stringW
{
    public string String;
    public float Weight;

    public stringW(string _String, float _Weight)
    {
        String = _String;
        Weight = _Weight;
    }


    public static implicit operator string(stringW StringW)
    {
        return StringW.String;
    }

    public static implicit operator stringW(string String)
    {
        return new stringW(String, 0);
    }

    public static explicit operator float(stringW StringW)
    {
        return StringW.Weight;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(stringW left, stringW right)
    {
        return left.String == right.String && left.Weight == right.Weight;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(stringW left, stringW right)
    {
        return left.String != right.String || left.Weight != right.Weight;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "{" + String + ", " + Weight.ToString() + "}";
    }
    public string ToString(int digits)
    {
        return "{" + String + ", " + Math.Round(Weight, digits).ToString() + "}";
    }

    public static stringW operator +(stringW left, string right)
    {
        left.String += right;
        return left;
    }
    public static stringW operator +(stringW left, float right)
    {
        left.Weight += right;
        return left;
    }

}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string a = "test1";
    stringW b = "test2";
    b.Weight = 1;

    Console.WriteLine(a + " " + b + " Three: " + 3);
    Console.WriteLine(a + " " + " Three: " + 3);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} Three: {2}", a, b, 3);


    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

And here's the Console output:

```
test1 test2 Three:
test1  Three: 3
test1 {test2, 1} Three: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have an implicit operator string

Console.WriteLine has many overloads, the ones I am interested in here are:

```
public static void WriteLine(object value);
public static void WriteLine(string value);
```

You are expecting C# to use the first one (with object parameter) and call your .ToString and print the 3.

What actually happens, is that C# converts your stringW struct to string using the implicit operator which returns a string without the 3. And calls the second overload.

Normally, you shouldn't make implicit operators that causes you to lose information. For example `myInt = (int)myLong` must be explicit because you can lose the information in higher bits, but `myLong = myInt` can be made implicit because you don't lose information.

In case of stringW to string you lose the weight value. So it's recommended to make it explicit.

Another note, don't name the property of your struct `String`. Not only this is a name of an existing type `System.String`, it is one of the most commonly used types. So I recommend using another name to avoid confusing people reading your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll change it to explicit and rename the String to text or something.